# Deploy SPA from VSO to Azure Web app or VM

Tags: git, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

Hi we are working on SPA which we store in visual studio online. I try set up CI for it.

I associate our VSO with Azure Subsription and connect them each other in manage.windowsazure.com It works fine.

the first opportunity I tried was set up Windows File Copy through winRM but I ended up on the problem by adding remote machine name to TrustedHostList (It´s possible to get name of remote machine name from VSO ??)

the second opportunity I tried was set up deployment from portal.azure.com

[image]

You can add setting for Azure Web App for deployment but this way create xaml build definiton and that is problem because We have no .sln,csproj.... files in repository. It´s just single page app with standart packages.json etc. files

When I try start xaml definition build without .sln it will not work

When I follow articles , which are orientated toward asp.net mvc it works everything fine.

Could you recommend me some relevant and proven article or source where can i find soulution.

Or witch is the best way how deploy spa project from VSO to Web App or Azure WM

[image]

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

CI deployments to Azure using Visual Studio Online only support Visual Studio Web Applications or Azure Cloud Service project, it doesn't work for single page files. So, for your scenario, you need to create one Web Application (note: not Web Site) to host these single page app files.

Then follow steps in this article for the details about Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Online and Git:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso-git/

This link is helpful to you as well: https://github.com/Azure-Readiness/DevCamp/tree/master/HOL/build-single-page-app-with-webapi-and-angular